# store $key as array weird result

Tags: php

```
$highest = max($data);
$check = array();
$resultype = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value){
if($value === $highest){
echo $key;

//output (t1,t3);

$check = $key;
}
}

echo $check; 

//ouput(t3);
```

Why is it working when I store the `$key` into a array ?
When I echo in `$key` in foreach I get what I want (t1,t3) but when I store into and array and output it out side foreach, it only give me (t3).
How do I fix this and store `$key` into a array with the result I wanted?

Comment: $check[] = $key; ... and then print_r($check);

Comment: you can get the all key as an array without loop by `array_keys` function. php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: wont work , Array to string conversion

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing `$key` in the array, you're assigning it to the variable `$check`.

Try using `$check[] = $key;`.

Comment: wont work , Array to string conversion